# PHP Fatal Error required File

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu

I am getting the following error from Apache/2.4.25 Ubuntu  17.04 and PHP Version 5.6.32-1

```
Warning: require_once(/ui-2.1/component/HTMLUtil.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/gateway/Interim.php on line 11
```

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/ui-2.1/component/HTMLUtil.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/etc/apache2/htdocs/html/shares:/etc/apache2/htdocs/html/languages:/etc/apache2/htdocs/html/adodb:/etc/apache2/htdocs/html/adodb/session:/etc/apache2/htdocs/html/educ/includes:/var/www')
>   in /var/www/html/gateway/Interim.php on line 11

but this code work exactly on Apache/2.2.17 Ubuntu PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11

i think this problem is related to this code `define('ROOT_PATH',str_repeat("../",substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/')-2));`
Ideas?

Comment: Check all folders again, maybe you have some misspellings?

Comment: Add more info like the value of `str_repeat("../",substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/')-2)`, your server root folder etc. This is incomplete information.

Comment: i cant find vlaue of str_repeat("../",substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/')-2‌​)

Comment: but  server root folder /etc/apache2 and SCRIPT Folder /var/www/html

Comment: value of str_repeat("../",substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/')-2‌​) is 1 ;and value of $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is HTMLUtil.class.php

Comment: all folder correct

Comment: can anyone explain this code :define('ROOT_PATH',str_repeat("../",substr_count($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'/')-2));